# How to export the regression table for the results with robust standard error or clustered standard error with package lfe?

Tags: r, regression, texreg, lfe

Using the package `lfe`, I can generate the regression results with either robust standard error or clustered standard error using command `felm`.

For the standard regression, I can export the regression table with the `texreg` package using function `screenreg`, `texreg` or `htmlreg`. However, if I want to get the regression with the robust standard error in `lfe` package, I need to add the option `robust=T` in the `summary` function, therefore, I wonder how I can export the regression table using `texreg` package in the case I mentioned here? See below for the demo code.

```
library(lfe);library(texreg)
OLS1<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width |0|0|0, data = iris)
summary(OLS1, robust=TRUE)
summary(OLS1)

OLS2<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width |0|0|Species, data = iris)
summary(OLS2)

screenreg(list(OLS1,OLS2),caption = "Linear regression")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the line `s <- summary(model)` to `s <- summary(model, ...)` in the extract function in the `texreg` package:

```
library("texreg")

extract.felm <- function(model, include.nobs = TRUE, include.rsquared = TRUE, 
                         include.adjrs = TRUE, include.fstatistic = FALSE, ...) {

  s <- summary(model, ...)
  nam <- rownames(s$coefficients)
  co <- s$coefficients[, 1]
  se <- s$coefficients[, 2]
  pval <- s$coefficients[, 4]

  gof <- numeric()
  gof.names <- character()
  gof.decimal <- logical()
  if (include.nobs == TRUE) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$N)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num.\ obs.")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE)
  }
  if (include.rsquared == TRUE) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$r2, s$P.r.squared)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "R$^2$ (full model)", "R$^2$ (proj model)")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.adjrs == TRUE) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$r2adj, s$P.adj.r.squared)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Adj.\ R$^2$ (full model)", 
                   "Adj.\ R$^2$ (proj model)")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.fstatistic == TRUE) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$F.fstat[1], s$F.fstat[4], 
             s$P.fstat[length(s$P.fstat) - 1], s$P.fstat[1])
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "F statistic (full model)", 
                   "F (full model): p-value", "F statistic (proj model)", 
                   "F (proj model): p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
  }

  tr <- createTexreg(
    coef.names = nam, 
    coef = co, 
    se = se, 
    pvalues = pval, 
    gof.names = gof.names, 
    gof = gof, 
    gof.decimal = gof.decimal
  )
  return(tr)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("felm", "lfe"), 
          definition = extract.felm)
```

Then you should be able to hand over a `robust = TRUE` argument to `screenreg` or `texreg` calls:

```
library("lfe")
OLS1 <- felm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width |0|0|0, data = iris
OLS2 <- felm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width |0|0|Species, data = iris)

# regular standard errors
screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2), caption = "Linear regression")

# robust standard errors
screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2), caption = "Linear regression", robust = TRUE)

# mixing regular and robust standard errors
tr1 <- extract(OLS1)
tr2 <- extract(OLS1, robust = TRUE)
screenreg(list(tr1, tr2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider a workaround way using `override.se` and `override.pvalues` in the `screenreg` function. That is, we first save the robust standard error and the corresponding p-values. When print out the table, we over-ride the default values. You will find that the stars representing the significance value will be automatically updated.

Below is the reproduced example. I intentionally created `iris2`. When you run the regression, the significance level is different for robust (p=0.004 -- 2 stars) and non-robust standard errors (p=0.015 -- 1 star). After you over-ride the standard errors and p-values, `screenreg` gives 2 stars.

```
library(lfe);library(texreg)
# Create the data iris2 which would have difference significance levels
# for robust and non-robust standard errors
iris2 = rbind(iris[1:100,], iris)
OLS1<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width|0|0|0, data = iris2)

# you will see the difference in significance level below
summary(OLS1)
summary(OLS1, robust=TRUE)

###############################################
# Save the robust standard errors and p-values
###############################################
RSE1 = coef(summary(OLS1, robust=TRUE))[,"Robust s.e"]
RpVlaue1 = coef(summary(OLS1, robust=TRUE))[,"Pr(>|t|)"]

# the second regression
OLS2<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width|0|0|0, data = iris)

RSE2 = coef(summary(OLS2, robust=TRUE))[,"Robust s.e"]
RpVlaue2 = coef(summary(OLS2, robust=TRUE))[,"Pr(>|t|)"]

screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2), override.se = list(RSE1, RSE2),
          override.pvalues = list(RpVlaue1, RpVlaue2),
          caption = "Linear regression")
```

You will find for the first regression OLS1, there are two stars resulted from the robust standard error!

For clustered standard error, if you have specified the clustered in `felm` as you did

```
OLS2<-felm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width |0|0|Species, data = iris)
```

The default value will be the clustered standard error. That is, there is no need to over-ride.